# Drupal duplicate breadcrumb

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, breadcrumbs

I know I can find this question everywhere but I don't find any solution that works for me, I have the problem of duplicate breadcrumb, for example I have a blog page and my breadcrumb is :

Home > Blog > Blog

The first "Blog" have a link to the blog page, and the second nothing, I just want to keep the second one but I don't find why I have these duplicates.

I don't use any module for breadcrumb, I just have a rewrite breadcrumb in the theme but it's not used for this page.

I also have some others pages who have the similar problem

For my breadcrumb rewrite i'm only doing this :

```
if(arg(0)=="node" && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2)=="participants") {
  $br = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $br[3] = t("Participants du voyage @title",array("@title"=>$node->title));
  drupal_set_breadcrumb($br);
}
```

And it's in the init of a module

Comment: " but it's not used for this page" are you sure ? did you check condition of apply from your modifications ? Also you can define breadcrumb with hook `MYTHEME__breadcrumb($vars)`

Comment: I add the thing I change in the breadcrumb on my post

Comment: which url pattern do you to catch ? node/12345/participants ? you want a content type in particulary ?

Comment: This is for another page who don't have any relation to the ones who have duplicate term, it's just for showing you the only thing i'm doing to my breadcrumb